What, exactly, is "OverflowAPI"?
The description on the OverflowAPI website is rather vague marketing speak:

OverflowAPI is a subscription-based API service that provides continuous access to Stack Overflow’s public dataset to train and fine-tune large language models.

There already is a Stack Exchange API.
What are the differentiators between a paying customer using OverflowAPI and the publicly available Stack Exchange API?
The website also mentions "Stack Overflow's API solutions", which indicates that more than one API product may be available for purchase.
However, beyond this high-level marketing page, it seems like other details are hidden behind the "Become a partner" form. I suspect that if I filled out that form, I wouldn't get any information.
Even companies that offer commercial APIs tend to offer public documentation about what they get. One example that I've worked with in the past is the AccuWeather APIs. Even though some of their APIs are gated behind a paywall, the API documentation is available. Are there plans to make API documentation available so we understand more about how our intellectual property is being packaged and exposed to paying customers?
